# Tell bounty-givers that they will have 24 hours after the deadline to reward the bounty

Tags: feature-request, bounties

Stack Overflow currently gives no indication to the setter of a bounty that he will have 24 hours after the deadline to award the bounty. Please add some sort of message, both in the "Bounty Creation Wizard" and also in the Bounty Text that the user can see for the duration of the week.

Comment: You could always just read the FAQ... "The bounty period lasts 7 days. Bounties must have a minimum duration of at least 1 day. After the bounty ends, there is a grace period of 24 hours to manually award the bounty."

Comment: Yes... I'm sure it's on display at the local planning office ;) but I agree that it'd be nice if the information popped up at a relevant time for those that don't go looking for the information that they don't yet know exists...

Answer (score 2):

It seems to me that the "your bounty expires soon" email reminder would be a perfect place for this.

Not sure it makes sense to add it to the creation process...

Once the bounty expires, the bounty banner changes to something like "This question had a bounty worth +X reputation from Y that ended just now; grace period ends in Z", so we could be more clear about what the grace period means there as well.